# how can i have a gridview with independent scrolling columns

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I made a gridview that consists of imageviews. Data is gathered with base adapter that parses xml.

Gridview has 3 columns. And i want that each column can be scrollable independently. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can potentially use three ListViews (or three ScrollView + vertical LinearLayout) in a horizontal LinearLayout to achieve this effect. GridView offers a single scrolling surface.

Comment: i also thought that approach. I saw this effect in iphone and just curious about that gridview has similar effect in android. If so, i guess i wont make an effort for that.